# Android linear acceleration accuracy

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager

I have an app where I poll the sensors for acceleration data and save the XYZ values to a SQL DB. Codewise it is pretty simple:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        sensor = event.sensor;

        int i = sensor.getType();
        if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            accelerometerMatrix = event.values;
        } else if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
            gyroscopeMatrix = event.values;
        } else if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_GRAVITY) {
            gravityMatrix = event.values;
        } else if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_MAGNETIC) {
            magneticMatrix = event.values;
        }

        //insert into database

    }
```

`MainActivity.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` is just a field I set in my MainActivity class.

If I set this to `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` I notice that the values that get stored to my DB are fairly low in accuracy (only 2 decimal places). But if I use the hardware accelerometer `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELERATION` then the accuracy is much higher (6dp)

My question is, am I retrieving the linear acceleration values incorrectly to cause me to only get 2dp of accuracy? Or is this just a limitation of how the sensors are fused together in Android? If its the latter, how do I get higher accuracy in my accelerometer values, after filtering out gravity, when working with fused sensors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot change accuracy of the hardware sensors on Android. You can only adjust sampling period with [registerListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int)) method from `SensorManager` class or monitor accuracy change with [onAccuracyChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html#onAccuracyChanged(android.hardware.Sensor,%20int)) callback from `SensorEventListener` interface.

It looks that you are retrieving sensor readings correctly in your code snippet.

I would suggest doing the following things:

- try to perform the same measurement with just **one sensor** and
  check if application behavior has changed - maybe multiple readings
  are causing measurement inaccuracy?
- try to run this application on a different device if you have one and verify if behavior and accuracy is different - maybe accuracy of the sensors is different on different devices?
- check accuracy and datatypes in your database and verify if it handles more accurate data correctly

If you don't notice any difference after applying mentioned suggestions, I think we cannot do anything about increasing sensor readings accuracy.

Moreover, I performed some experiments with sensors on Android some time ago using Nexus 5 and Nexus 6 and I see that different sensors has different accuracy as you also noticed. According to my knowledge, we cannot control that from the Android SDK API level.